# is unicode( codecs.BOM_UTF8, "utf8" ) necessary in Python 2.7/3?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, byte-order-mark

In a code review I came across the following code:

```
# Python bug that renders the unicode identifier (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF)
# as a character.
# If untreated, it can prevent the page from validating or rendering 
# properly. 
bom = unicode( codecs.BOM_UTF8, "utf8" )
r = r.replace(bom, '')
```

This is in a function that passes a string to Response object (Django or Flask).

Is this still a bug that needs this fix in Python 2.7 or 3? Something tells me it isn't, but I thought I'd ask because I don't know this problem very well.

I'm not sure where this came from, but I've seen it around the Internet, referenced sometimes in association with Jinja2 (which we are using).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you encountered it in a code review, maybe you could ask the author where the code initially did come from and if there is some test case for it? Because I’ve never seen it before, and don’t think there is a real need for it (at least I never had a problem with not doing it).

Comment: @poke there is a good chance the author was me. lol

Comment: Now that’s a late reply xD

Comment: @poke Better late than never. :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Unicode standard states](http://www.unicode.org/unicode/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) that the character `\ufeff` has two distinct meanings. At the *start* of a data stream, it should be used as a byte-order and/or encoding signature, but elsewhere it should be interpreted as a *zero-width non-breaking space*.

So the code

```
bom = unicode(codecs.BOM_UTF8, "utf8" )
r = r.replace(bom, '')
```

isn't just removing the utf-8 encoding signature (aka BOM) - it's also removing any embedded *zero-width non-breaking spaces*.

Some earlier versions of python did not have a variant of the "utf-8" codec which skips the BOM when reading data streams. Since this was inconsistent with the other other unicode codecs, a "utf-8-sig" codec was introduced with [version 2.5](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig), which does skip the BOM.

So it's possible the "Python bug" mentioned in the code comments relates to that.

However, it seems more likely that the "bug" relates to *embedded* `\ufeff` characters. But since the Unicode Standard clearly states they can be interpreted as legitimate characters, it is really up to the data consumer to decide how to treat them - and therefore *not* a bug in python.

Comment: In Unicode 3.2, this usage as a zero-width non-breaking space is deprecated in favor of the "Word Joiner" character, U+2060.This allows U+FEFF to be only used as a BOM. [What should I do with U+FEFF in the middle of a file?]- http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM

Answer (score 0):

BOM is a byte sequence that specifies what Unicode encoding is used.

BOM is used to inform the decoder how to transform bytes to Unicode (where Unicode can have different binary representation).

It doesn't make any sense to try to put BOM inside a Unicode string.

Comment: the code posted by OP deletes the byte order mark, not puts it